# graphics.h gives no output

Tags: c++, c, bgi

```
#include <graphics.h>
#include <conio.h>


int main()

{
    int gd = DETECT, gm;
    initgraph(&gd,&gm, "");
    for (int i=200;i<400;i=i+25)
    {
        for (int j=200;j<400;j=j+25)
        {
            circle(i,j,100);
        }
    }
    getch();
    closegraph();

    return 0;
}
```

I download  http://winbgim.codecutter.org/
extract and copy-paste

```
graphics.h
winbgim.h
libbgi.a
```

I set `Settings => Compiler => Linker` settings. and add `-lbgi -lgdi32 -lcomdlg32 -luuid -loleaut32 -lole32`
I change line 302 as int `left=0, int top=0, int right=INT_MAX, int bottom=INT_MAX,`
and im using .cpp not .c but there is still no outputs
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89M9H.png)

Comment: You might consider checking for errors as shown in the example here: http://winbgim.codecutter.org/V6_0/doc/initgraph.html It might also be better to start small. Draw one circle and if that works then you can incrementally change things and see where it breaks.

Comment: This [Microsoft page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/previous-versions/visualstudio/foxpro/c0000005-error-troubleshoot) says "A C0000005 error is memory error. Specifically, a C0000005 error is an access violation error caused by a buffer overrun."

Comment: What should i do about A C0000005 error @WeatherVane dont understand solution in Microsoft page

Comment: i copy-paste the example at winbgim.codecutter.org/V6_0/doc/initgraph.html but still nothing out @RetiredNinja

Comment: Setting `left=0, int top=0, int right=INT_MAX, int bottom=INT_MAX` is unwise. It needs `4611686014132420609` pixels for a 32-bit `int`.

Comment: okey so what settings should i use

Comment: i also download and set compiler TDM-GCC-32 but still nothing outs

Comment: Getting this ancient crap to run on modern PC is probably 10 times harder than learning the basics of some modern GUI library which is actually used in the real world. Do you wish to learn GUI programming or do you wish to learn how to become a MS DOS emulator installer?

Comment: lol i should give up and learn c++ or python @Lundin

Comment: @lordwile Which GUI library to use doesn't have anything to do with choice of programming language. BGI is an ancient graphics library for Borland compilers. It worked with C, C++, Pascal and probably some other languages too.

Comment: @lordwile if you're satisfied with my answer then you can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is perfect. You just forget to give path for **BGI folder**.
In my machine BGI path is `"C:\TurboC++\Disk\TurboC3\BGI"`. Since I am running it on **DOSBox**. So path becomes `"C:\\TurboC3\\BGI"`

Here is the working code.

```
#include <graphics.h>
int main()
{
    int gd = DETECT, gm, i, j;
    initgraph(&gd,&gm, "c:\\TurboC3\\BGI");
    for (i=200;i<400;i=i+25)
    {
        for (j=200;j<400;j=j+25)
        {
            circle(i,j,100);
        }
    }
    getch();
    closegraph();
    return 0;
}
```

**BGI (Borland Graphics Interface):-** Graphics interface for windows machine. Functions like circle(), arc(), line() etc are defined in it. `graphics.h` is like driver to draw graphics and use BGI interface.

You're getting error `BGI Error: Graphics not initialized (use 'initgraph')`. You can't sees it because screen quickly out. In TurboC click on `Window` option at right top most. And then click on `Output`. Then output window will be at the bottom.

Error:-
[image]

**Output:-**
[image]